# Increasing the heap size in a traditional Websphere Application Server (WAS) 8.5 using the administration console?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Heap dump when trying to run a large EAR application. Need to increase heap size. It is not a liberty server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer through the administrative console.

> Login to Administration console
>
> Expand servers -> Websphere application servers -> Click on your server name (eg: server1)
>
> Expand Java and Process Management under Server Infrastructure (in configuration tab)
>
> Click on Process definition -> Java virtual machine
>
> Update Initial heap size & Maximum heap size as required.
>
> Apply and save the changes
>
> Restart the Server

.